# power bi filled maps wont plot for the state of UT

Tags: bing-maps, powerbi

I am having  an issue getting the filled map visual to work.
Would appreciate any pointers to correct this issue.

I am trying to create a filled map visual to show:

- a) Count of Providers in the State (this count also controls the
  color saturation on the map)
- b) Count of Networks in the State

The data is setup like this:

[image]

The map fills correctly, except for the state of Utah, 
If I create a "Table" visual with the same data,
the counts for Utah show up correctly (so I know it is not a data or calculation issue).

I have set the "State" field in Power BI Modeling to a Data Category of "State or Province"

I have tested the following as part of my troubleshooting:
1) Replacing all the state abbreviations with fully spelled state names
   (eg replace "UT" with "Utah", and it still will not plot)
2) If I change the Map configuration to use Zipcodes instead of the State, the map will plot the zip codes correctly for the state of UT.

Screen shot of the map with UTAH not filled in, and the data used to fill the map....

[image]

Comment: It's working fine for me in the August 2017 build (2.49.4831.521) What version are you using?

Comment: I am on the same version: Version: 2.49.4831.521 64-bit (August 2017)

Comment: @teylyn can you share your powerBI settings for the "State" field:  DataType=text? and DataCategory=State or Province?

Comment: Just wanted to add that the state of UT will plot if I change the settings for the DataCategory to "Place" instead of "State or Province", but then the other states get messed up: IN plots to India, CO plots to Colombia, ID= Indonesia.   Sigh.

Comment: This looks to be a Power BI specific issue. I've tested Bing Maps directly, Power Maps and the filled maps in Excel and they all work correctly for UT.

Comment: @momo, yes, data type text and category State or Province.

Answer (score 0):

I have a kludgy solution to this problem. 
It involves creating a new column in the table with the following formula:

US_States = IF('TableName'[AddressState]="LA","Louisiana,USA",'TableName'[AddressState]&",USA").

What this does is add a ",USA" suffix to each state abbreviation, and if the state="LA", spell out the state to "Louisiana, USA"- this is because Bing maps would otherwise plot LA as "Los Angeles" (good grief!).

You must set the new column of "US_States to a data category of "Place"

Hope someone else can benefit from this post. –